# $(x + y)^s \le x^s + y^s$ for $0 < s \le 1$

Tags: inequality

I'm reading a book on valuations on a field(Hasse's number theory).
He says $(x + y)^s \le x^s + y^s$ for $0 < s \le 1$ and $x, y \ge 0$.
I tried to prove it but failed.

Another question: Is $(x + y)^s \ge x^s + y^s$? where, $s \gt 1$ and $x, y \ge 0$.

OK, the first questions is duplicate, but **IS THE SECOND QUESTION DUPLICATE, TOO?**

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914819/xyp-leq-xpyp-for-positive-x-y-and-0p1?rq=1

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat I have already flagged this as duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that for $0\le a\le 1$ and $0<s\le 1$, we have
$a^{1-s}\le 1 \implies a\le a^s$

Note that if $x=y=0$ the inequality is trivially true. For $x+y>0$, using the observation we have
$$\left(\frac{x}{x+y}\right)^s+\left(\frac{y}{x+y}\right)^s \ge \frac{x}{x+y}+\frac{y}{x+y}=1$$
$$\implies x^s+y^s \ge (x+y)^s$$

Answer (score 1):

If $y=0$ then we have equality. If $y>0$ then 
devide by $y^s$ to get $(1+t)^s\ge 1+t^s$ Consider the function $f(x)=(1+t)^x-1-t^x$ Note $f'(x)=\log (1+t) (1+t)^x- t^x\log t>0$  since $(1+t)^x>t^x>0$ and $\log (1+t)>\log t$ we have that $f$ is increasing but $f(0)=0$ so $f(s)\ge 0$ for $s\ge 0$ which implies the inequality.